# Enabling ARC is not showing my classes

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have follow guides to enable `arc` . clicked `edit->refactor->convert to arc` .
than i have a checkbox that shows classes , but all of them are `cocos2d` classes, and i can't see my app classes (my 2 main classes i created ) . the guide say not to check the cocos2d classes, but i don't have any other thing to check expect them ,since mine is not there.

so, i don't understand, when starting a project and creating a class- is it automatic using ARC ? this is why i don't see my classes in there ?

Do i have to check that box of cocos2d classes using the cocos2d v2.0 ?

I can't understand how exactly to processed and when does arc is used automatic.

Thanks.

Comment: Cocos2D isn't ARC-enabled is it?  So how do you propose to link against it?  Have you built it as a static library?

Comment: @trojanfoe why would you need all your libraries to support arc to use it? you can enable arc on a per file basis... ARC is a compile time thing not a runtime thing.

Comment: @BradAllred I agree; however it certainly simplifies things when you work on a project and you know that all the files in the project use the same memory management scheme.  However I'd like to hear something from the OP that lets me know he's considered all this and is on top of it.  EDIT: having said I agree; ARC does require runtime support.

Comment: @trojanfoe ARC itself doesn't require runtime support, however, zeroing weak references do apparently require runtime support. I cannot seem to locate actual documentation regarding runtime requirements. If you have a link please share.

Comment: @trojanfoe not exactly, but this discussion is falling outside the scope of the question. I did find the [relevant docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#runtime) stating that zeroing weak references require runtime support (now obvious), but it still appears you can use arc with the unsafe variety of pointers without runtime support.

Comment: to clarify: for zeroing weak references runtime support is required, which is built into iOS 5.0 and newer and OS X 10.7 and newer. ARC is still available beginning with iOS 4.0 and OS X 10.6 (64-bit apps only) but when targeting these OS versions you can't use the weak/__weak keywords. The alternative is __unsafe_unretained which is similar to weak except it doesn't nil the pointer, leaving it dangling. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: one sure way (besides checking Build Settings) to find out whether a given class is ARC or not is by implementing an empty -(void)dealloc{} --- if the compiler complains about a possibly missing [super dealloc] call it's not using ARC, otherwise it is. You can also send retain/release message to an object, if it's ARC the compiler will complain about these.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, yes your classes will be automatically created under ARC (assuming it's turned on in whole project).
The best way to check which files are under ARC is to go

```
your project (left pane, Navigator) -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources
```

Files with `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flags are **not** under ARC

So to sum up: set cocos2d to not use ARC and check if you classes are using ARC (if you want to use it)

[image: Xcode Build Phase]

Note: on above picture files main.m, AppDelegate, HelloWorldLayer, IntroLayer, FirstStory are of course files created by me.

Comment: thats a good unswear but how would i disable all cocos2d files from using arc ? i know that if i set the project to use arc (under complier language in build settings) it gives many cocos2d errors. i wonder whats the way to do that , and why are these guides are using the refactor menu .

Comment: It's simple. Just enter Build Phases, search for Compile Sources double click on column Compiler Flags in row corresponding to a file and you will see pop-up window. There just type `-fno-objc-arc` and voilà! Your files are not under ARC. 
Note: you can select many files and with one click, type `-fno-objc-arc` command only once.